# Jquery dropdown change value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown list i want to change the view on jquery change events

Html code is

```
<select id="pu_viewToLoad" class="select-dark" name="viewToLoad"></select>
```

Js code

```
    $("#pu_viewToLoad").change(function(evt) {  
    evt.preventDefault();

    var index = parseInt($("#pu_viewToLoad option:selected").val(), 10);

    if (index >= 1000) { 
        index -= 1000;
        console.log("Changing to 2D view: " + _views2D[index].name);
        switchSheet();
        loadView(_viewerSecondary, _views2D[index]);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Changing to 3D view: " + _views3D[index].name);
        switchSheet();
        loadView(_viewerSecondary, _views3D[index]);
    }
});
```

This function is not executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use:

```
var index = parseInt($("#pu_viewToLoad option:selected").attr("value"), 10);
```

Or

```
var index = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

Please change accordingly. And make sure you are running the above function inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: I too suspected like that, but that is not at all a problem. http://jsfiddle.net/6s2nhm17/ It seems some other problem must be persisting with OP's code

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Hi da... Yes, it works too. Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: Thanks its working i have put above code in $(document).ready()